# How to exit a form in a different class than where the form was created

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this project where I need to include multiple forms. The problem is that my first form will not close. I have two classes, `Beta` and `Form1`. I am trying to exit the `WinForm` created by `Form1` through the class `Beta` using this code:

```
Form1 Form1 = new Form1();
Form1.Close();
```

That did not work, and I went to explore other options. I decided to add the closing of the form in the button click event where I transferred from the `Form1` class to the `Beta` class, but that did not work either. It would close the entire program completely. Here is the code where I did that:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); // Closes the program if I include this here
        Beta.ExecuteMainUIThread();
        this.Close(); // Unaccessible code
    }
```

My question is that where I would I exit the original form and launch another one, all while trying to keep the program running

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what exactly you want to do. Are you saying you click a button on the `Beta` form to create a new `form1` and then you like to be able to close `form1` from within `beta`?

Comment: @cost Beta isn't a form, it's a normal class. I just want to exit the previous form and launch a new form in the beta class, but using `this.Close()` or `Form1.Close()` is not working

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what your question is, but from what I understood you have a parent and a child form and you want to open/close the child from the parent, perhaps you could do something like:

(in the Parent):

```
private ChildForm _childForm;

private void btnOpenChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_childForm == null)
    {
        _childForm = new ChildForm();
        _childForm.Show(this);
    }
}

private void btnCloseChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_childForm != null)
    {
        _childForm.Close();
        _childForm.Dispose();
        _childForm = null;
    }
}
```